# Should my WiFi extender use a different SSID to the rest of the network?

Tags: wifi-configuration, ssid, wireless-extender

So I got my hands on a Netgear WiFi extender to improve WiFi coverage in my home. In the setup instructions it tells me it will automatically create a new network called "[existingSSID]_ext" or something to that effect.

Would there be any negative impact to me renaming the SSID of the extender to the same SSID of my current network to create a "roaming" setup?